# Подскажите как выводить красиво элементы словоря и его ключи

Tags: python, словари

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def print_words():
    import string
    f = open('text.txt', 'r')       # чтение из текст файла
    f.seek(0)
    str = f.read().split()

    my_d = dict()
    my_set =set()

    for i in str:                   # пропускаю через множества
        my_set.add(i)

    for word in my_set:
        new_word = word.lower()
        new_word1 = new_word.strip(string.punctuation)  
        # удаление знаков припенания

        for ky in new_word1:
            if ky not in my_d:
                my_d[ky] = 1
            else:
                my_d[ky] += 1

    for y in my_d:
        print (y,'-',my_d[y])   # Вывод на экран

    f.close()
    return


print_words()
```

Comment: Исправьте код и опишите задачу подробно, а также укажите, что и где не получается. При чем в текущем виде кода вообще `format`? И почему, используя третий питон, вы пишете `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` и `print` без скобок? И еще, у вас файл никогда не закрывается, так как `f.close()` стоит после `return`.

Comment: ('\x81', '-', 70)
('\x80', '-', 85)
('\x83', '-', 27)
('\x82', '-', 103)

Comment: в 2.7 нужно `u` указать, попробуйте в 3.5 запустить

Comment: print (y,'-',my_d[y])   # u в этой строке?   u'y'     что-то не получается...   (У меня только 2.7 версия) Учимся только по ней пока...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print (y,'-',my_d[y])` замените на `print '%s - %d' % (y.decode('utf-8'), my_d[y])`

Comment: � - 70
� - 85
� - 27
� - 103     Уже лучше но все еще очень плохо :)

Comment: В какой кодировке данные в text.txt?

Comment: print '{0} - {1}'.format(y, my_d[y])     вот так,тоже самое.

Comment: Текст на русском языке.

Comment: Русский - это понятно, но кодировка-то какая? utf-8, cp866, cp1251, koi8-r?

Comment: И ещё один важный вопрос: в какой операционной системе запуск происходит?

Comment: А как же это проверить? есть метод?

Comment: Windows Operation System

Comment: Некоторые редакторы показывают кодировку. Редактор FAR, например. А откуда файл взялся?

Comment: Проблема в том, что кодировка данных в файле отличается от кодировки консоли - cp866. Варианта два - либо перекодировать данные в файле каким-либо сторонним способом, либо в момент загрузки данные в str менять кодировку с помощью Python.

Comment: файл из урока по python.  А как можно в ходе процесса поменять коддировку?

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на файл. Так быстрее разберёмся.

Comment: https://github.com/pavel8silber/Py_repo.git

Comment: Кодировка UTF-8. Я исправил ответ.

Comment: В ГидХабе исправили?

Comment: Нет, ответ, в котором мы ведём переписку. Добавилось `.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Выдает ошибку: http://snag.gy/TazOB.jpg

Comment: str = f.read().decode('utf-8').split()   Добавил еще в начале... все ок, спасибо!